# Assigning Variables with Conditional Statements

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I'm in the process of teaching myself PHP and was wondering if I could get a little help from the community after having little luck running Google searches for ideas.

I have two files - photos.php and profile.php

In photos.php I have the following:

```
if (($results[0][exterior] == "Sebring Orange Metallic") && ($results[0][model] == "Coupe") && ($results[0][ztk_performance] == "Yes") && ($results[0][wheels] == ""))
    {
        $photo='<div class="post-image details-img"><a href="images/coupe/2019-corvette-zr1-sebring-orange-ztk.jpg" class="zoom">
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <img src="images/2019-corvette-zr1-sebring-orange-ztk.jpg" alt="2019 Corvette ZR1 Coupe in Sebring Orange Metallic with the ZTK Track Performance Package" title="2019 Corvette ZR1 Coupe in Sebring Orange Metallic with the ZTK Track Performance Package"></a>
</div><br />';
    }
elseif (($results[0][exterior] == "Sebring Orange Metallic") && ($results[0][model] == "Coupe") && ($results[0][ztk_performance] == "No") && ($results[0][wheels] == ""))
{
    $photo='<div class="post-image details-img"><a href="images/coupe/2019-corvette-zr1-sebring-orange-non-ztk.jpg" class="zoom">
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <img src="images/2019-corvette-zr1-sebring-orange-ztk.jpg" alt="2019 Corvette ZR1 Coupe in Sebring Orange Metallic" title="2019 Corvette ZR1 Coupe in Sebring Orange Metallic"></a>
</div><br />';
    }
```

In profile.php, I am calling photos.php and querying a database.  I simply want to print out the results of that variable:

print $photo;

Basically, the image isn't coming up, so I'm trying to figure out if I'm my logic is wrong or my syntax?

Comment: These conditions seem unusually specific and are usually a sign you need a lookup table of some sort.

Comment: It looks like you missed the quotes in the keys (for example, you need `$results[0]['exterior']` instead of `$results[0][exterior]`). If it won't help, please, print `$results` array content just before the `if` statement (`print_r($results);`) and add it to the question.